# Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState call from Azure Function returns null even after long wait

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

Here's the sequence of actions performed inside Azure powershell function -

```
if (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $name) {
    #This should Delete the KeyVault and put it into "Removed" state
    Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName $name -Force
}

$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 16
$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

do{
   Write-Host "Waiting for 2 minutes before checking InRemoved status of KeyVault '$name'"
   Start-Sleep -s 120
   $vault = Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState | Where-Object { $_.VaultName -eq $name }
} while ($stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds -lt $timeout.TotalMilliseconds -and $vault -eq $null)
            
if ($vault) {
  Write-Host "Removing '$name' Key Vault which is in Removed State"
  Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName $name -Force -InRemovedState -Location $vault.Location
}
```

It seems, the "Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState | Where-Object { $_.VaultName -eq $name }" never returns the vault object and finally the function times out after the given timeout (16 minutes here). I tried from just putting a normal sleep of 20 seconds to this timeout based do-while and the Get-AzKeyVault -InRemovedState never gives already Removed Vault's object.

The same logic works perfectly fine locally with no wait time required at all.

Am I doing anything wrong here from Azure powershell function? Suggestions / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the same thing for a teardown script and I also encountered the issue you're describing. I ultimately ended up with this. It doesn't *feel* as safe, but Azure doesn't provide much feedback on the delete/purge on Key Vaults. This has been working for me for several months.

```
# Key vaults that are soft-delete enabled must be deleted and then purged
# Delete them first because the resource group can't be targeted after they are in the deleted state
$keyVaults = Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

foreach($kv in $keyVaults)
{
    Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName $kv.VaultName -ResourceGroupName $kv.ResourceGroupName -Force
    Remove-AzKeyVault -VaultName $kv.VaultName -Location $kv.Location -InRemovedState -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: What I'm seeing in error logs is - My function app service principal does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action'. So, when the 1st Remove-AzKeyVault runs, it deletes the keyvault successfully and puts it into "deletedVaults". Then when it tries to delete that "deleted Vault", it finds the authorization to do so, is not available. Though when creating the KeyVault itself I have an "Access Policy" set to allow "Purge" on Secrets for that KeyVault. Is Purge Secrets access not same as Purge KeyVault itself.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on that but it does make sense that if you don't have purge access on Certificates or Keys then you wouldn't be able to purge the vault. Our service principal has purge access to all three and it works. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

The Purge access on Access Policy only grants the Purge - Keys, Secrets and Certificates permissions, whereas to actually purge (permanently delete) a soft-deleted KeyVault itself, the Managed Identity of the Function App needs to have a Subscription Level Role assigned to it (in Azure RBAC) which grants it permission to execute the action - "Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action".

Once this role was granted to the MI of Function App, and the Purge Access Policy was also available, the script could easily soft-delete and permanently delete both the Secrets as well as the KeyVault itself.